# Android: changing private static final field using java reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

[Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

I followed the instructions in the link above to change a private static final field using java reflection. I have an object named "data." Inside "data," there is a private static final variable named "type." I want to set "type" to be null.
Here is my code.

```
Field field = data.getClass().getDeclaredField("type");
field.setAccessible(true);
Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
field.set(data, null);
```

I tried doing this on Java 1.7 with similar code and it worked. But running this code on Android produces the following error:
**java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: modifiers**

I guess "modifiers" is not a field in the Field class on Android.

How do I fix this?

Comment: You...can't change the _modifiers on a class field_ at _runtime._

Comment: I can according to that link.

Comment: Do remember that the Java compiler can inline values of primitive static final fields. Doing this sort of reflection magic could lead to bizarre behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works for non-static fields.

```
Field field = data.getClass().getDeclaredField("type");
field.setAccessible(true);
field.set(data, null);
```

Comment: This worked. But why? 
Does ART remove the final modifier or does it simple allow to access it anyway?

Comment: This works, because the first object in the `field.set(...)` function is the object to modify NOT the field

Comment: data is not static in this case?