# Logs and performance, Android (SurfaceView)

Tags: android, performance, surfaceview

I've created a game and every tick of the game loop this log occurs

> 09-05 07:53:20.213 27150-27240/com.x.y I/SurfaceView: Locking
>   canvas... stopped=false,
>   win=android.view.SurfaceView$MyWindow@32beabb4 09-05 07:53:20.226
>   27150-27240/com.x.y I/SurfaceView: Returned canvas:
>   android.view.Surface$CompatibleCanvas@34b823dd

How to prevent this log from occurring? I'm worried it is affecting performance.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

The only solution I have found so far is an ugly hack:

```
private void disableSurfaceViewLogging() {
    try {
        Field field = SurfaceView.class.getDeclaredField("DEBUG");
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(null, false);
        Log.i(TAG, "SurfaceView debug disabled");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "while trying to disable debug in SurfaceView", e);
    }
}
```

## Explanation

SurfaceView has a constant DEBUG which switches the logging. Somehow it is true (when you look at the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java) you'll see that it should be false). I couldn't find any other, more "proper" way around.

I relied on the following answers:

- [Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)
- [Android: changing private static final field using java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185453/android-changing-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

Comment: Reflective access to DEBUG will throw an exception when targeting API 33 and above :(

Comment: If only there was a "non hack" solution...